# How to attach a hyperlink to a cell to navigate to a shape?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I need to add a hyperlink to a given cell for navigating to a specific shape. I Googled but can't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in Sheetx in the same Workbook (Workbookx.xlsx):

```
=HYPERLINK("[Workbookx.xlsx]Sheetx!shape","SHAPE")
```

where the array to be selected has been named `shape`.  The cell in which this is entered should display `SHAPE` (the friendly name).

Further details at http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-select-edit-or-delete-a-hyperlink-HP010096304.aspx including for changing sheets, other workbooks, Macintosh etc.